Logon Batch Script Running for Standard Users but not Admins
I have a simple AD lab set up with one DC and one local host. There are three user profiles, one standard user, one local admin, and one domain admin.
I've created a batch script to just map a folder on the DC's admin account desktop. I've also used GPO to make this script run at logon, however it only maps the drive to the standard user's account on logon. I can't seem to figure out why the admin accounts don't receive this.
Any tips would be extremely appreciated

While "gpresult" showed that the script was running on the Domain Admin account, the drive was still not showing up in Windows Explorer.
The work-around I found for this was to just change the GPO from User Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Scripts TO User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps. This seems like the more dedicated way to achieve this sort of task, though someone can correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you!

Please check Event Viewer - Windows - Application Logs and Event Viewer - Application and Services Logs - Microsoft - Windows - Group Policy logs on the computer where you expected the administrator to run the logon script and map the drive.
On the same computer logoff and logon as Domain Administrator, then run "gpresult /z" command from command line and in the output User Configuration part, check which polices have been applied to the user (Administrator) and which have been filtered out and not applied.
Your GPO should be linked to the container / OU where Administrator (Domain Admin) user resides or to an upper layer in Active Directory. By default you should apply your GPO to whole domain for the built-in Administrator (Domain Admin) user to apply this GPO. Users folder  in which Administrator user resides is a container and group policies can not be directly applied to this container but will inherit from "Default Domain Policy". So for Administrator (Domain Admin) user to run the logon script you should link your newly created GPO to whole domain similar to "Default Domain Policy".
The local administrator of the member server (Local Administrator) can not apply a domain GPO which has a logon script in user setting. The member server local administrator will only apply the logon script if the domain GPO which you have created has the logon script in its computer configuration and the domain GPO applies to the member server.
